# angularJS nth-child dont work in ng repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, css-selectors

I'm trying to change the background color of every second row of content that is written to the page with the ng-repeat.
I got it working... kind of. 
As per my current Code it is working only for font color, not for background color.

Here is my code. Please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 25px 0;">
<div ng-repeat="katt in minaKatter" class="cat-row-ads test" ng-if="!katt.isDeceased && katt.canBeBreedingMale"> 
    <div class="tableContainer test col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg,{{katt.imageId}}" alt="" class="row-image" style="margin-right: 10px; max-width: 40px;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; line-height: 30px;" ng-bind="katt.name"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" style="line-height: 30px;">
            <div ng-if="katt.avelshane && katt.status == 1">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">ANNONSERA</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="katt.annonsTyp == '1'">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">TILLHÖR</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="katt.annonsTyp == '3' && katt.status == 1">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">ANNONSERA</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <a href="create-male-ad.php?catId={{katt.id}}" ng-if="(katt|| katt) && (katt== 2 || !katt)" class="btn btn-back btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Skapa / Redigera annons</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div></div>

CSS:
.tableContainer {
    padding: 5px 8px; 
}

.test:nth-child(odd){
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: the css is mostly from bootstrap to layout the divs. And then its only some styling on font and labels...

Comment: Most likely the background color is set by a higher rated css property, most likely by bootstrap. You could see this by inspecting the element in chrome and view which styles is applied to the nth-element

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the nth-child class you have applied is incorrect. It will check for the nth-child of the corresponding class name. The HTML should be changed like.

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 25px 0;">
<div ng-repeat="katt in minaKatter" class="cat-row-ads test" ng-if="!katt.isDeceased && katt.canBeBreedingMale"> 
    <div class="tableContainer col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <img src="data:image/jpeg,{{katt.imageId}}" alt="" class="row-image" style="margin-right: 10px; max-width: 40px;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; line-height: 30px;" ng-bind="katt.name"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" style="line-height: 30px;">
            <div ng-if="katt.avelshane && katt.status == 1">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">ANNONSERA</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="katt.annonsTyp == '1'">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">TILLHÖR</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="katt.annonsTyp == '3' && katt.status == 1">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">ANNONSERA</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <a href="create-male-ad.php?catId={{katt.id}}" ng-if="(katt|| katt) && (katt== 2 || !katt)" class="btn btn-back btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Skapa / Redigera annons</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div></div>
```

there is no need for `test` class in the element with `tableContainer` class name

Please check the snippet below.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.minaKatter = [{imageId: 0}, {imageId: 1}, {imageId: 2}, {imageId: 3}]
});
```

```css
.tableContainer {
    padding: 5px 8px; 
}

.test:nth-child(odd){
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="katt in minaKatter" class="cat-row-ads test"> 
    <div class="tableContainer col-xs-12">
     Test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i removed the other class test. But still the nth-child is applied only to font color and nothing with the background color. :/

Comment: @Lacon Please check the snippet added.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using different classes for your elements, and add a rule over even/odd indexes of your ng-repeat, using the **ng-class** tool:

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 25px 0;">
    <div ng-repeat="katt in minaKatter" class="cat-row-ads test" ng-if="!katt.isDeceased && katt.canBeBreedingMale"> 
        <div ng-class="{1:'tableContainer test-red col-xs-12', 0:'tableContainer col-xs-12'}[$index % 2 == 0]" class="tableContainer test col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <img src="data:image/jpeg,{{katt.imageId}}" alt="" class="row-image" style="margin-right: 10px; max-width: 40px;">
                <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; line-height: 30px;" ng-bind="katt.name"></span>
            </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" style="line-height: 30px;">
            <div ng-if="katt.avelshane && katt.status == 1">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">ANNONSERA</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="katt.annonsTyp == '1'">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">TILLHÖR</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="katt.annonsTyp == '3' && katt.status == 1">
                <span class="label-style label label-default">ANNONSERA</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <a href="create-male-ad.php?catId={{katt.id}}" ng-if="(katt|| katt) && (katt== 2 || !katt)" class="btn btn-back btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Skapa / Redigera annons</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.tableContainer {
    padding: 5px 8px; 
}

.test-red{
    color: red;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```